# A silly silly question

Tags: lateral-thinking, humor

Grandpa and I went on a nice camping trip away from it all for hiking, fishing, hunting, camping, kayaking you name it.

After a rather adventurous yet successful day we were walking back to the tent when suddenly Grandpa giggled and said

> " You know *this* just proves  1 = 2 doesn't it son?"
>
> I looked at him and then it hit me. Silly but kind of right.

What was he holding?

Comment: To be pedantic, it should have been - "...just proves 1= 2 doesn't it _grandson_ ?"...:-)

Comment: LOL   Grandpa calls every young person 'son'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is he holding...

> A bird in his hand? Which equals 2 (you and your grandpa) in the bush, as the old adage goes.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing it is:

> A kayak paddle

Comment: please explain your answer. thanks!